# Prevent data from being deleted after running test with maven

Tags: maven, testing

I am new in maven. I am running a test from my command prompt. These tests generate a database. My issues is that after the test finish the data are deleted.
I want to maintain the generated database to use it later. Is there a way to do this in maven?
This is what I run through command prompt:

```
        mvn -Dtest=TestDynamicLayers test
```

I saw that there is a similar question here but it doesn't solve my problem:
           [Prevent data from being deleted after test run with Hibernate / Spring / Maven / MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224892/prevent-data-from-being-deleted-after-test-run-with-hibernate-spring-maven)

Thanks
Dimitris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect the deletion of data from tests to be a Maven behaviour, this is something that would typically occur in a "teardown" step in the test or as the thread you link to suggests through automated rollback for @Transactional tests.

Assuming the test runs, In your example TestDynamicLayers.java is the only test being executed so the data deletion would be something either in one of the test methods or one of the "after" steps. e.g. if using JUnit annotations the teardown would be expected in a method annotated @AfterTest.

Generally I would advise against using a test normally run in the test phase of a Maven build to have side effects as this would mean multiple test executions could have different results. Deletion of test data after test execution is desirable for this reason. Personally I would go further and use an in-memory database for unit tests.

I suggest you extract the data creation code for data you want to retain and execute this outside a test by wrapping it with a main() method. If you want the data to be also created by tests you can invoke the same code, keep the currently unwanted data deletion and invoke the data creation directly using java -classpath